# Deserialize and cast as Class Object in python

Tags: python, json, serialization

I have the following class:

```
class base(ABC):
     id: int
     date: datetime
     __Type: int

    @abstractmethod
    def doStuff(self):
        pass

class Foo1(base): 
     def __init__(self):
         #initialize stuff

     def doStuff(self):
         #i need to access this function somehow after deserializing
class Foo2(base):
     def __init__(self):
         #initialize stuff

     def doStuff(self):
         #i need to access this function somehow after deserializing
```

I push the object into the service bus by doing the following:

```
obj = json.dumps(self, default=lambda o: o.__dict__)
self.push_to_queue(obj)
```

And when i retrieve back from the service bus i do the following:

```
obj = self.pop_from_queue()
slave_task = json.loads(str(obj))
if slave_task['__Type'] == 1:
    #create Foo1 and call doStuff of Foo1
if slave_task['__Type'] == 2:
    #create Foo2 and call doStuff of Foo2
```

in C#, i used to use JSON.NET and pass TypeNameHandling attribute as true and it did the "magic", perhaps there's something similar i can do in python?

**EDIT:**
I realized this question was a bit ambiguous for what exactly I am wanting to achieve.

Over all goal: I have many classes like the one above (Foo) that all process different things ("Slave-Classes"). 
I have a main Leader class that generates those "Slave-Classes" and pushes out to the Service Bus. Then my Slave-machines read the json objects from the service bus and start doing its thing.

Currently i have an additional field "Type" that i manually attach to the json, then at the read time I have if-else statements that reads "Type", and depending on what it is, it creates the respective class and starts processing.

I am wanting to somehow get rid of the if-else statements that figure out the type of the class the json object has and let it trigger the function dynamically.

I hope it cleared the question up a bit more!

Comment: JSON doesn't have any built-in mechanism for serializing code.  Its only types are numbers, strings, bools, null, and arrays and maps of those.  You would have to use something on top of JSON that extracted the source code of the method and serialized it in with the JSON.

Comment: What is your goal after serializing? Do you want to `rebuild`? If so, you can overwrite `__repr__` that generates a string that can regenerate Your class.

Comment: i'll edit my question as i realize its a bit ambiguous of what my overall goal is

Comment: Question edited. Hopefully it makes more sense now. Apologize for the confusion.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "trigger the function dynamically".  Why store `1` as the type instead of `"Foo1"`?  Then you could look up the class name in the module dict if you want.

Comment: I would be inclined to just bite the bullet and implement a `from_json` classmethod.

Comment: There's usually some popular libraries tailored to a task like this: e.g. [marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: @BrenBarn whether i store 1 or "Foo1" is really out of scope. Either way i will need to do If-else check to see what kind of class it is. As my slave-classes are growing i am starting to have a lot of different classes like Foo1 and Foo2, so i am wanting to completely get away from this nasty if-else statements. and by trigger i mean call the funciton.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga marshmallow seems somewhat promising, ill take a look at that!

Comment: @Gio it does the job and saved me time re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga i ended up using marshmallow with some customization and additions, so you if you want to post it as an answer I will accept it as it led me to the solution.